# Дан массив действительных чисел, размерность которого N. Подсчитать, сколько в нем отрицательных, положительных и нулевых элементов

Tags: java, циклы

Нужно подсчитать кол-во положительных, отрицательных и равных 0 элементов, но код выдает кол-во элементов в массиве. Причем ответ 8 выводится в той с, где условие: num[i]>0
В чем проблема моя?..

```
public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args){
          int[] a={-10,0,5,0,2,8,3,-1};
          task11(a);
     }
     static void task11(int[] num){
           int c1=0, c2=0, c3=0;
           for ( int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
              if(num[i]>0  && num[i]!=0){
                   c1=c1+1;
              }
              else if (num[i]<0 ){
                   c2=c2+1;
               }
               else if (num[i]==0){
                   c3=c3+1;
               }}  
System.out.println("Положительных чисел: "+c1+"; Отрицательных: "+c2+"; Равных нулю :"+c3);
    }  
 }
```

Ответ:  Положительных чисел: 8; Отрицательных: 0; Равных нулю :0

Comment: приведенный код работает правильно - http://ideone.com/l1JseD

Comment: Вы правы. Отдельно код работает, возможно причина в других методах. 
Спасибо)